# Remove large file from git staging area

Tags: bash, git, terminal, git-push, git-reset

I've tried to push a commit containing a file exceeding the 100 MB limit and see the message

```
remote: error: File data/clean/new/all_listings_clean.csv is 327.92 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

So I deleted the file locally (I didn't need it) and tried `git reset` and then `git add -A` + `git commit -m "..."` and `git push origin master` but I see the same error message.

I've also tried `git reset HEAD^`, `git reset HEAD -- .`, `git reset HEAD~`, `git rm --cached`.

I keep getting this error! It can't figure out how to tell it to refresh my staging area, recognize that the large file is not there anymore, and go ahead and push the commit without it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: It looks like it may answer my question -- thank you. I'm sad there's not a simpler solution! Ideally it would just forget about what I was trying to push and try again with a fresh commit.